# Javascript Object Child Reference?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a javascript object and I need to reference the value of one of it's children. The child should be part of an array.

This works:

```
this.manager.response.highlighting[doc.id]['sentence_0002']
```

But this doesn't:

```
this.manager.response.highlighting[doc.id][0]
```

I don't know which `sentence_000*` numbers are going to be returned, so I want to reference it by it's array number.

```
this.manager.response.highlighting[doc.id].length
```

doesn't return anything either.

Here is a portion of the xml document that was turned into the javascript object:

```
<response>
  <lst name="highlighting">
    <lst name="http://www.lemonde.fr/international/">
      <arr name="sentence_0005">
        <str> puni pour sa gestion de la crise Geir Haarde a été condamné pour avoir manqué aux devoirs de sa </str>
```

What I need to access is the value in `<str>`. `doc.id` is successfully set to `http://www.lemonde.fr/international/`.

Comment: It would be more useful to show the javascript object that is created from the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `highlighting[doc.id]` has a property with a name like `sentence_xyz`, there is **no** positional order to that property, but you can find out what keys exist using a `for..in` loop:

```
var key, val;
var obj = this.manager.response.highlighting[doc.id];
for (key in obj) {
    // Here, `key` will be a string, e.g. "sentence_xyz", and you can get its value
    // using
    val = obj[key];
}
```

You may find you need to filter out other properties, which you can do with the usual string methods, e.g.:

```
for (key in obj) {[
    if (key.substring(0, 9) === "sentence_") {
        // It's a sentence identifier
    }
}
```

You may also find [`hasOwnProperty`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.5) useful, though I'm guessing this is a deserialized object graph from a JSON text response, in which case `hasOwnProperty` doesn't really come into it.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder Using key & val worked like a charm. Makes sense now. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @TJCrowder—"0" won't "work" even if the object is an array if the value has been assigned to a property named 'sentence_0002' and not to one named '0'. I suspect that's what the OP discovered using for..in.

Comment: @RobG: Yeah, not sure where my head was, that and the "if it's a non-array object". It doesn't matter whether it's an array or not! :-)

Comment: @SmoothAlmonds: Glad that helped. You may find this article helpful: [*Myths and realities of `for..in`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your question:

> I have a javascript object and I need to reference the value of one of it's children. The child should be part of an array.
>
> This works:
>
> ```
> this.manager.response.highlighting[doc.id]['sentence_0002']
> ```
>
> But this doesn't:
>
> ```
> this.manager.response.highlighting[doc.id][0]
> ```

That indicates that the object that `this.manager.response.highlighting[doc.id]` references has a property named `sentence_0002` and that it doesn't have a property named "0".

That object might be an Object or Array (or any other object, like a Function or even a DOM object). Note that in javascript, Arrays are just objects with a special length property and some handy inherited methods that can mostly be generically applied to any object.

So whether the object referenced by `this.manager.response.highlighting[doc.id]` is an Array or an Object makes no difference in the above, since the property you're after seems to have a plain object name, not a numeric index as might be expected if it was an Array and was being used as an Array.

Answer (score 0):

You can now find the length of your object, but the index will not be numeric, it will be 'sentence_000*'

To do so :

```
 var obj = this.manager.response.highlighting[doc.id],
     indexes = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj),    
     indexLength = indexes.length;
 for(var counter = 0; counter < indexLength; counter++){
    obj[indexes[counter]] == val // obj[indexes[counter]] is same as this.manager.response.highlighting[doc.id]['sentence_000*'] 
 }
```